# asynchronous function does not wait until called asynchronous function was executed in nodejs/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am calling an asynchronous function which fetches data and subsequently modifies it from another asynchronous function. The latter, however, does not wait until the data was modified in the function called. Currently it is only possible to return the data not anything handled inside the called function since the inside return is not waited for. I tried to async await for the called function but this did not work.

This is the initial call of the function

```
exports.addRequest = async (req, res) => {
    const requestResult = await RequestsModel.addRequestData(req.params.test)
    return res.send(requestResult);
};
```

And this is the function called

```
exports.addRequestData = async (test) => {

    await Requests.findById(requestId)
        .then((requestData) =>{
            //(01)
            if (requestData[type].filter(req => req[compareId] === requestDataObj[compareId]).length !== 0) return "exists";
            if (requestData[complementaryType].filter(req => req[complementaryCompareId] === requestDataObj[complementaryCompareId]).length !== 0) return "exists_complementary";

            //(02)
            requestData[type].push(requestDataObj);
            return requestData.save();
        }, (err) => {
            return err;
        });
};
```

I remove the parameters since they work fine.
The only scenario where I return data is when I return the entire lower mongoose function body. For the promise and data handling the upper function does not seem to wait.

Any help is highly appreciated since I just started working with nodejs and asynchronous functions.

Thanks
Jakob

Comment: You should restructure `.addRequestData()` so that it takes advantage of `async` and `await`. Currently, the function does not return anything. Mixing `async`/`await` with `.then()` is usually a sign that something is wrong.

Comment: So it makes more sense to return the fetched data from the .addRequestData() to the waiting function then handle it there and call another function which updates / removes etc.

Comment: Something like that. Basically, instead of `.then()`, assign the returned value of the `await` in that function to a variable. Then the code in the `.then()` moves directly into `addRequestData()`. Then the `return` statement returns back to the calling function. Now, I'm not sure what that `.save()` does; if it's also `async` you'd want to return the result of `await` on that call.

Comment: Ok I see. The logic behind this is that one user can request another and I double check if there is an existing request going on and if not I push the request as a sub document into a mongodb document and then save it afterwards.Thank your very much for your help!

Comment: `requestData[type].push(requestDataObj);` <-- where is requestDataObj defined?

Comment: this comes from the request body but for simplicity reasons I have remove all parameters.  I just wanted to demonstrate that if this return is triggered the initial await function did not wait for it

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying `exports.addRequestData` like this.

(I agree with [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy))

```js
exports.addRequestData = async (test) => {
    let requestData = await Requests.findById(requestId);
    if(requestData.isValid){ // success case
     // do operations on requestData and return it 
    } else { // error case
    // return error
    }
}
```

Also there is no mention of `requestId`. How is that?

Comment: I removed all parameters. They worked fine. I implemented your approach and it worked just fine. Thanks